# javascript function does not work within jquery $(document).ready block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a `JavaScript` function from an `onclick` trigger.

`HTML` section:

```
<div class="my_radio">
    <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="1" onclick="my_func()"/>  first button
</div><!-- end of class my_radio -->
```

And the `JavaScript` code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function  my_func(){
            alert("this is an alert");
        }
    });
</script>
```

It does not work.

But if i keep the `JavaScript` function out of the  `$(document).ready()` code, it works. Following is the relevant code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function  my_func111(){
            alert("this is an alert");
        }
    });

    function  my_func(){
        alert("this is an alert");
    }
</script>
```

1) Why does not the first `JavaScript` code snippet work?

2) How can I get the first `JavaScript` code snippet working ?

**EDIT :**

SO FAR AS I KNOW, `$(document).ready()` is executed when the web page loads completely. So how can I prevent `my_func()` to be active before or after the complete page-loading if I write `my_func()` outside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: duplicate question > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242541/function-not-calling-within-an-onclick-event

Comment: like Alien said > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a function defined in jQuery.ready available globally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223305/jquery-global-function)

Comment: oh let me understand what u said

Comment: @glavić , unintentionally duplicate.. will it affect my post negatively?

Comment: Don't know, it is not up to me. I suggest, that you do ALL your javascript in .ready(). This means, that you use .click() insted of hardcoded onclick="".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all about javascript execution contexts and scope.

Everything that you define within a function is know only in this function.

In your first test, the function `my_func()` can only be used within the ready callback (and in the inner other objects). You can't reference it outside.

In your second example, the function `my_func()` is global to the document and accessible from anywhere.

I recognize this is maybe a verry simple explanation :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you define your function within a callback, you can only use it within this callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function something(){
    alert('test');
  }

  //..

  something(); // Will work
}

something(); // Won't work
```

Comment: the necessary and unnoticed thing to me was, everything inside the $(document).ready is defined within a callback function

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet doesn't work, because in in the function `my_func111` is defined within *the local scope of an anonymous function* passed as an argument in your `$(document).ready` call.

You can fix your code by placing the function definition to the document scope and calling it inside ready function such as:

```
function my_func(){
   alert("this is an alert");    
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   my_func();
});
```

Comment: what will have for onclick to do then?

Comment: Now take your time and read through your answers with patience. They already contain all the information you need to understand and answer your problem!

Comment: i tried with ur code. the alert box shows up as soon as the page loads. clicking is not required there.

Comment: Well obvious if you don't want the alert to appear onload, then remove the my_func() call from $(document).ready?

This as far as I will go with my answer. I will leave the rest for you to figure out!

Comment: Istiaque: if your problem has been solved, consider accepting an answer in order to get help in the future as well!

Answer (score 0):

I presume by "it does not work", you mean it says "my_func is not defined" or similar?

When you define a function within a function, the inner function is not visible outside of the outer function (unless it is part of the outer function's return statement).

You'll need to learn about closures, a good tutorial on which can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Comment: yes, says 'undefined'. ur link says : The site's security certificate is not trusted! answer to my ques 2? getting familiar with closure ..

Comment: sorry, i was mistaken in my previous comment to u.  does not say anything.

Answer (score 0):

You'll add a global variable `isReady`. The `$(document).ready` callback section will change it to `true`.

Both your function and the `isReady` variable must be defined outside the callback of the `$(document).ready`, so that they can be seen from outside the scope of the callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isReady = false;    // outside the onReady callback

function  myFunc(){     // also outside the onReady callback
    if (!isReady) return; // abort if not ready

    alert("this is an alert");
}


// the onReady callback
$(function(){  // the newer jquery shorthand for: (document).ready(function(){
    isReady = true;
});

</script>
```

Your HTML code needs no changes. - I changed the names to use JS and HTML conventions, but essentially it's the same as what you originally wrote...

```
<div class="divMyRadio">

<input type="radio" id="myRadio" value="1" onclick="myFunc()"/>  first button

</div><!-- end of class divMyRadio -->
```

I
As a side note: The newer JQuery uses `$(function(){`  as shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){` to make things easier for you.