# AJAX Call from JS Function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to call a javascript function from an html.erb file. The javascript function makes an Ajax call to a specified controller, sending an item id from the URL as a parameter.

I keep getting syntax and "can't find variable: callAjax" errors.

in the html.erb file

```
<%= image_tag('star.png', :style => 'margin-right: 10px', :onclick => "callAjax('/book/favorite/'+book.id);") %>
```

in the js file

```
function callAjax(path) {
  console.log(path);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost:3000'+path,
        data: path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        success:{
          //do something
        }
    });
}
```

in the book controller

```
  def favorite
    book=Book.find(params[:id])
    current_user.favorite_books << book
  end
```

Comment: "can't find variable: callAjax" suggests that function isn't properly defined. Could you update your question with more code? Btw, `book.id` should be interpolated in that `onclick` string value.

Comment: Might be you problem will solve here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242541/function-not-calling-within-an-onclick-event