# Button onclick to change class, but afterwards can't change class again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to set a button for toggling between dark/light mode. My goal is to set the button such that after I click the "dark mode" button, it changes to a "light mode" button. And after I click the "light mode" button, it switches back to dark mode and vice versa.

Now, what I have is that once I click the "dark mode" button, it does change to "light mode", but I can't change it back to dark mode anymore. I referred to https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp and [Function not calling within an onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242541/function-not-calling-within-an-onclick-event) to try to remedy this with toggleClass but it still gave me the same error.

Here is the javascript code portion.

```
$(() => {
// on click, set dark mode
$(".darkmode").on("click", () => {
    $('body')[0].className = "darkmode";
    $('p')[0].className = "darkmode";
    $('h2')[0].className = "darkmode";
    // change the screen colours displaying the dice value etc
    $('.badge-light').addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-light');
    // switch to light mode button
    $('.btn-dark').addClass('btn-light lightmode').removeClass('btn-dark darkmode').text("Light mode");

  })
  
  
// on click, set light mode
$(".lightmode").on("click", () => {
    $('body')[0].className = "";
    $('p')[0].className = "";
    $('h2')[0].className = "";
    $('.badge-dark').addClass('badge-light').removeClass('badge-dark')
    $('.btn-light').addClass('btn-dark darkmode').removeClass('btn-light lightmode').text("Dark mode");
  })
})
```

which is affecting the following html

```
<button class="btn btn-dark darkmode mr-1">Dark mode</button>
```

I suspect the error has got to do with the site not reading the lightmode function? Afterall, when I check the console, I see that the class has successfully updated, so the lightmode class is already present, just that the click still registers the previous darkmode class? I have not encountered such an issue before, and I am not sure what type of error is this so I am unable to search it right.
[image]

Edit: Based on acdcjunior's comment, I now have

```
// on click, set dark mode
  $(document).on("click", ".darkmode", () => {
      $('body,p,h2').toggleClass("darkmode");
      // change the screen colours displaying the dice value etc
      $('.badge-light').addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-light');
      // switch to light mode button
      $('.btn-dark').addClass('btn-light lightmode').removeClass('btn-dark darkmode').text("Light mode");
      
    })
    // on click, set light mode
    $(document).on("click", ".lightmode", () => {
        $('.badge-dark').addClass('badge-light').removeClass('badge-dark')
        $('body,p,h2').toggleClass("lightmode");
        $('.btn-light').addClass('btn-dark darkmode').removeClass('btn-light lightmode').text("Dark mode");
      })
```

which is great since it toggles the dark/light modes, but with 2 clicks. What confuses me is that when I load the page and first click "dark mode", it changes everything in 1 go, but subsequently, I require 2 clicks on "light mode"/"dark mode" to change the background first, then the light/dark mode button and the badge together.

Also, I should add that when I use the original version without toggle class like this,

```
// on click, set dark mode
  $(document).on("click", ".darkmode", () => {
      $('body')[0].className = "darkmode";
      $('p')[0].className = "darkmode";
      $('h2')[0].className = "darkmode";
      // change the screen colours displaying the dice value etc
      $('.badge-light').addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-light');
      // switch to light mode button
      $('.btn-dark').addClass('btn-light lightmode').removeClass('btn-dark darkmode').text("Light mode");
      
    })
    // on click, set light mode
    $(document).on("click", ".lightmode", () => {
        $('body')[0].className = "";
        $('p')[0].className = "";
        $('h2')[0].className = "";
        $('.badge-dark').addClass('badge-light').removeClass('badge-dark')
        $('.btn-light').addClass('btn-dark darkmode').removeClass('btn-light lightmode').text("Dark mode");
      })
```

The problem returns back to the original one where I can only click dark mode once and subsequently, any clicks on the button does not render anything. I find it weird though, because the console does show that the event has been updated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first bind the events, there is no $(".lightmode") on the screen, therefore the second listener never gets installed.

Bind the listeners to the document and use `on` in the `$(document)`. This will install the listeners to the document from the start and handle any changes to classes:

```js
$(() => {
    // on click, set dark mode
    $(document).on("click", ".darkmode", () => {
      
      
    // on click, set light mode
    $(document).on("click", ".lightmode",() => {
```

---

On a side-note, those three lines that set the classes on `body`, `p` and `h2` could be just `$('body,p,h2').toggleClass("darkmode");`

Comment: Thank you! This is one step closer to the goal. I now need to click the buttons twice to enable the dark/light mode, since it first toggles the class to change the background colour, and then add/remove the classes.

Comment: Alright, it seems doable. But would you mind creating another question for that? You should post the updated code in the new one, should make it easier for us to help you